# Set the Selected Attribute on the Selected Option in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following implementation which triggers the change event whenever I change the select values.

```
 $(element).on("change", function() {



            });
```

Now, inside the on change function I need to get the option that is selected and then attach the selected = selected attribute to it.

So I can get the value using the following:

```
  $(element).on("change", function() {

                alert($(this).find(":selected").text());

            });
```

But the selected value is not reflected in the user interface. It still shows no selection.

Comment: *"But the selected value is not reflected in the user interface."* Are you saying that the selection is immediately reset after the user makes a selection? That's not normal, so code must be doing that. There shouldn't be a reason to set the attribute explicitly. Please provide more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get selected option value:

```
$(element).on("change", function() {
  var item=$(this);
  alert(item.val())
});
```

or

```
$(element).change(function() { 
  var item=$(this);
  alert(item.val())
});
```

[fiddle to play.](http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/9pqwjj6w/)

```js
var element = $("#options");

$(element).on("change", function() {
  var item=$(this);
  alert(item.val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="options">
  <option value="select">Select</option>
  <option value="select 1 value">Select 1</option>
  <option value="select 2 value">Select 2</option>
</select>
```

The  way to get the selected dropdown value on change:

Answer (score 0):

Inside that function: $(this).find(':selected').attr('selected', 'selected') ;

That will do it. But why do you need it? You can get the selected option with the :selected pseudo selector.

http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $("#select").on("change", function() {
     $(this.selectedOptions[0]).attr("selected", "selected");
 });
```